# Drop _id in MONGO return

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to drop the _id in a MONGO aggregate query, by using {'_id': 0}?
In the following, where would the {'_id': 0} go??

```
db.books.aggregate([
   { $group : { _id : "$author", books: { $push: "$title" } } }
 ])
```

Comment: `db.books.aggregate([
   { $group : { _id : "$author", books: { $push: "$title" } } }, { $project:{_id: 0}}
 ])`

Comment: `_id` is required in `$group` stage what you want is `$project`

Comment: So add another `$project` to your pipeline if you need to drop `_id`. However, adding `$project` for the sake of removing `_id` from the  end result does make much sense.

Comment: Thank you all but its not working. I've entered                       
       db.sal.aggregate([{$group:{_id: "SalAvg":{$avg:$job.Sal"}}}]) and not matter where I put the ("_id":0} the _id keeps appearing in the output.